# List command on Node.js debugger returning only [Function]

Tags: node.js, debugging, io.js

When running `node debug file.js` you are supposed to be able to call `list` to show the executing line plus the lines around it. When I do that all I'm getting is `[Function]`, why is that?

```
debug> list
[Function]
```

Here's an example file that I just tried debugging:

```
const h = require('virtual-dom/h');
const toHTML = require('vdom-to-html');

var tree = h('input', { type: 'submit', value: 'Add' });
var str = toHTML(tree);
```

No matter where I try "list" it says `[Function]`.

Comment: Does file.js contain a line similar to module.exports = function() {} ? You might not be able to inspect the object after it has been instantiated

Comment: No it does not contain an export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a function in the debugger. The reason it's printing out `[function]` is because you're not invoking it, but rather causing the repl to return the function that is `list`.

You need to call `list()`.

e.g.

```
> node debug logger.js
< Debugger listening on port 5858
connecting to port 5858... ok
break in logger.js:1
> 1 'use strict';
  2
  3 const bunyan = require('bunyan');
debug> list()
> 1 'use strict';
  2
  3 const bunyan = require('bunyan');
  4
  5 /**
  6  * Returns a configured bunyan logger
debug> list
[Function]
debug>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like something people in node.js IRC channel easily should have been able to answer.